# Delete the first character from a text file once it is read?

Tags: c, file, text, character

This is the code that I was working on, I need it to read one character from a text file at a time and then delete it but I'm sure how to delete it once it is read? Please can some one help

```
char readfromtf()
{
FILE *tf = fopen("string.txt", "r+");
char c;


if(tf == NULL) 
{
  perror("Error in opening file");
  return(-1);
}
else
{
  c = fgetc(tf);
  if (c == EOF)
  {
    fclose(tf);
    return 'x';

  } else 
  {
    fclose(tf);
    return c;

  }

 }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by *"delete it"*?  Do you want it removed from the file?  To do that, you will have to re-write the entire file, starting at the 2nd character.  One does not simply remove a character from a file.

Comment: sorry i am very new to this site, and not sure how to effectively use it, is it possible to just answer the question here?

Comment: If the file is not too large, load it into the memory and rewrite it to the text file after modifying.